# Error en un anlizador sintáctico y semántico yacc, hecho para lenguaje Pascal

Tags: pascal, yacc

Mi problema es que he probado mediante el terminal el compilar otros archivos .pas (Pascal) y todo ha ido bien, me seguía las reglas y en clase a las reglas definidas me segmentaba el código y posteriormente daba errores sobre algunas cosas (solo semánticas), el problema viene cuando he probado otro texto y se me muestra un error sintáctico como si no me detectase el id en este código. La foto es del error y el texto es del archivo .pas(texto a analizar)

```
program ejemplo;
const
PI = 3.1416;
var
a:integer;
i:integer;
b:real
c:string
begin
i := a; (*variable a sin inicializar*)
writeln("Introduce el valor: ");
readln(valor); (*variable valor sin declarar*)
writeln("Introduce el valor de la a: ");
readln(a);
writeln("Introduce el valor de la b: ");
readln(b);
i := a * b; (*tipos incompatibles en la instrucción*)
PI := 3.1595; (*modificación de valor de una constante*)
writeln(c); (*variable sin inicializar*)
end.
```

mi código es el siguiente, el que uso como .y de analizador

```
%{

#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void yyerror(const char* msg) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", msg);
}
int yylex(void);
FILE *yyin;


//estructura que tiene cada una de las variables que se utilizan en el programa
//gracias a esto podemos encontrar todo tipo de fallos en su declaracion, uso...
struct simbolo{
    char nombre[30];
    int tipo; //1 2
    int cte;//1 o 0
    int inicializado;
};

//COMENTARIO SOBRE EL ejemploPascal.l
// Lo unico que contiene este fichero .l es cada una de las declaraciones de tokens para el .y
//En la mayoria de los casos unicamente ha sido necesario escribir la palabra para traducirla como
//token,pero en el caso de los numeros enteros, reales, identificadores y cadenas se ha precisado de ponerlo en forma de expresion.
struct simbolo tablaSimbolos[50];
int dim = 0;
int pos = 0;


int buscarSimbolo(struct simbolo tablaSimbolos[], char nombre[30], int dim);


extern int nLineas;

%}


%union {
     int tipo;
     char nombre[30];
     char nombreVar[30];
}



%token <nombre> ID
%token PROGRAM
%token CONST
%token <tipo> NUM
%token <nombreVar>VAR
%token INTEGER
%token CADENA
%token REAL
%token STRING
%token BEGINn
%token END
%token WRITELN
%token READLN
%type <tipo> expr
%token '(' ')'
%token WHILE
%token IF
%token ELSE
%token THEN
%token AND
%token NOT
%token OR
%left '+' '-'
%left '*' '/'
%right '^'




%%
//aqui definimos la estructura general que tendrá el programa

programa:   cabecera seccionDeclaracionCtes seccionDeclaracionVariables seccionInstru '.'{printf("\n Todo correcto. Numero de lineas: %d \n",nLineas);}
   ;
cabecera: PROGRAM ID ';'{printf("\n Reconozco la cabecera");}
          ;

//estas son la declaracion de constantes y variables que son muy similares
//la principal diferencia a parte de su estructura es en el analisis semantico en su struct


seccionDeclaracionCtes: /*vacia*/
      | CONST declaracionCtes;

declaracionCtes: declaracionCte 
      | declaracionCte declaracionCtes; 

declaracionCte: ID '=' NUM ';'  {printf("\n Declaracion constante");
int pos = buscarSimbolo(tablaSimbolos,$1,dim);
    if (pos != dim){
        printf("\n ERROR lin: %d: identificador redeclarado",nLineas);}
else{
        //lo añado
        printf("\n Añado %s",$1);
        tablaSimbolos[dim].tipo = $3;
        tablaSimbolos[dim].cte  = 1;
        strcpy(tablaSimbolos[dim].nombre,$1);
        dim++;
}}
        |ID '=' CADENA ';'  {printf("\n Declaracion constante");
            int pos = buscarSimbolo(tablaSimbolos,$1,dim);
            if (pos != dim){
                printf("\n ERROR lin: %d: identificador redeclarado",nLineas);}
       else{
                //lo añado
                printf("\n Añado %s",$1);
                tablaSimbolos[dim].tipo = 3;
                tablaSimbolos[dim].cte  = 1;
                strcpy(tablaSimbolos[dim].nombre,$1);
                dim++;
       }};
       
seccionDeclaracionVariables: /*vacia*/
      | VAR declaracionVariables;

declaracionVariables: declaracionVariable
      | declaracionVariable declaracionVariables; 

declaracionVariable: ID ':' REAL ';' {
                               printf("\nDeclaracion variable entera");
                               int pos = buscarSimbolo(tablaSimbolos,$1,dim);
                               if (pos != dim){
                                      printf("\n ERROR lin: %d: identificador redeclarado",nLineas);
                               }
                                else{
                                      printf("\n Se introduce %s",$1);
                                      tablaSimbolos[dim].tipo = 2;
                                      tablaSimbolos[dim].cte = 0;
                                      tablaSimbolos[dim].inicializado=0;
                                      strcpy(tablaSimbolos[dim].nombre,$1);
                                      dim++;
                               }}
                    | ID ':' INTEGER ';' {
                                            printf("\nDeclaracion variable entera");
                                            int pos = buscarSimbolo(tablaSimbolos,$1,dim);
                                            if (pos != dim){
                                            printf("\n ERROR lin: %d: identificador redeclarado",nLineas);
                                           }
                                           else{
                                                  printf("\n Se introduce %s",$1);
                                                  tablaSimbolos[dim].tipo = 1;
                                                  tablaSimbolos[dim].cte = 0;
                                                  tablaSimbolos[dim].inicializado=0;
                                                  strcpy(tablaSimbolos[dim].nombre,$1);
                                                  dim++;
                                             }
                                          }
                    | ID ':' CADENA ';' {
                                           printf("\nDeclaracion variable entera");
                                           int pos = buscarSimbolo(tablaSimbolos,$1,dim);
                                           if (pos != dim){
                                                  printf("\n ERROR lin: %d: identificador redeclarado",nLineas);
                                           }
                                           else{
                                                  printf("\n Se introduce %s",$1);
                                                  tablaSimbolos[dim].tipo = 3;
                                                  tablaSimbolos[dim].cte = 0;
                                                  tablaSimbolos[dim].inicializado=0;
                                                  strcpy(tablaSimbolos[dim].nombre,$1);
                                                  dim++;
                                           }
                                                }
                                                


seccionInstru: BEGINn instrucciones END;

instrucciones: instruccion ';' | instruccion ';' instrucciones;

//dentro de cada instruccion podremos encontrarnos cualquiera de estos casos aqui planteados
instruccion: asignacion|visualizacion|lectura|ifelse|cwhile;

expr: expr '+' expr
    | expr '-' expr
    | expr '*' expr
    | expr '/' expr
    | expr '^' expr
    | '(' expr ')'
    | NUM
    | ID
    ;


//definimos para cada expresion cada una de las operaciones que podrá hacer
expr : expr '*' '*' expr 
                  {printf("error sintáctico de dos operadores juntos");}


exprBoolean: expr'<'expr|expr'>'expr|expr'>''='expr|
         expr'<''='expr|expr'='expr|expr'<''>'expr|
exprBoolean OR exprBoolean|exprBoolean AND exprBoolean|exprBoolean NOT exprBoolean|'('exprBoolean')';


                          


//lista constantes y variables
lista: ID ',' lista {
   printf("\nVisualizacion variable o constante");
   int pos = buscarSimbolo(tablaSimbolos,$1,dim);
   if(pos==dim){
        printf("\n ERROR lin: %d: identificador no declarado",nLineas);
   }else{
        if(tablaSimbolos[pos].inicializado==0 && tablaSimbolos[pos].cte==0){
               printf("\n ERROR lin: %d: variable no inicializada",nLineas);
        }
   }
}
        | ID {
           printf("\nVisualizacion variable o constante");
           int pos = buscarSimbolo(tablaSimbolos,$1,dim);
           if(pos==dim){
                printf("\n ERROR lin: %d: identificador no declarado",nLineas);
           }else{
                if(tablaSimbolos[pos].inicializado==0 && tablaSimbolos[pos].cte==0){
                       printf("\n ERROR lin: %d: variable no inicializada",nLineas);
                }
           }
        }
        | CADENA ',' lista | CADENA;



//estructura de asignacion 
asignacion: ID ':' '=' expr{
                      printf("\nAsignacion");
                      int pos = buscarSimbolo(tablaSimbolos,$1,dim);
                      if(pos != dim){

                          if(tablaSimbolos[pos].cte==1){
                                 printf("\n es una constante no se puede modificar su valor");
                          }
                    if(tablaSimbolos[pos].inicializado ==0){
                        tablaSimbolos[pos].inicializado=1;
                    }
                    if(tablaSimbolos[pos].tipo!=$4){
                        if((tablaSimbolos[pos].tipo==3 || $4==3)){
                            printf("\n ERROR tipos incombatibles en la asignacion");
                                               }else if(tablaSimbolos[pos].tipo==1 && $4==2){
                            printf("\n ERROR tipos incombatibles en la asignacion");

                                               }
                        }   
                                        }
                                   else{
                     printf("\nERROR lin: %d: identificador no declarado",nLineas);
  
                                   }};
                      
//estructura de visualizacion 
visualizacion: WRITELN '(' lista')'{
printf("\nEscritura de variable");
};

//estructura de lectura 
lectura: READLN '('ID')'{
                               printf("\nLectura de variable");
                               int pos = buscarSimbolo(tablaSimbolos,$3,dim);
                               if(pos==dim){
                                     printf("\nERROR lin: %d: identificador no declarado",nLineas);
                               }else{
                                     if(tablaSimbolos[pos].cte==1){
                                           printf("\nERROR lin: %d: no se puede alterar el valor de una constante",nLineas);
                                     }else{
                                           tablaSimbolos[pos].inicializado=1;
                                     }
                               }    
                           };


//estructura de un if else (con begin)
ifelse: IF exprBoolean THEN seccionInstru 
      | IF exprBoolean THEN seccionInstru ELSE seccionInstru;

//estructura de un bucle while
cwhile: WHILE seccionInstru;




%%

int main()
{
    yyin=fopen("ejemplo.pas","r");
    yyparse();
 
}


int buscarSimbolo(struct simbolo tablaSimbolos[],char nombre[50],int dim){
    for (int i=0;i<dim;i++){
        if (strcmp(nombre,tablaSimbolos[i].nombre) == 0){
            return i;
        }
    }
    return dim;
}
```

Necesito ayuda urgente, Gracias

Intente con el Terminal compilar lo previamente hecho pero el error es el que se muestra en la descripción que me da error, he probado a cambiar orden de cosas en el analizador pero no se si es solución.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error? Además: [¿Bajo qué circunstancias puedo agregar "urgente" o frases similares a mi pregunta para obtener respuestas más rápido?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4771). Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.